# How to disable marker clustering below a certain number of points in the viewport?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Is there an elegant way to disable clustering of points by marker clusterer if there are lesser than, say 30 points in the viewport?

When there are fewer points I would like to plot all of them.

Comment: Did you try the [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#MarkerClustererOptions), `minimumClusterSize` does that:

> minimumClusterSize    number  The minimum number of markers needed in a cluster before the markers are hidden and a cluster marker appears. The default value is 2.

Comment: I am sorry. I was referring the documentation of markerclusterer instead of markerclustererplus. Thanks a lot.